# Reg.exe not setting binary value as expected

Tags: powershell, cmd, system-administration, gpo

Not strictly Powershell, but have it nestled within. I'm trying to add this regkey to hide the taskbar:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2]
"Settings"=hex:28,00,00,00,ff,ff,ff,ff,03,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,3e,00,00,00,1e,
 00,00,00,00,00,00,00,66,03,00,00,40,06,00,00,84,03,00,00
```

I'm using:

```
reg.exe Add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3" /v Settings /T REG_BINARY /d '30 00 00 00 fe ff ff ff 03 02 00 00 03 00 00 00 3e 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5c 03 00 00 a0 05 00 00 84 03 00 00 60 00 00 00 01 00 00 00' /f
```

But when added the hex values do not translate to what expected as above. Any ideas if I'm missing something or adding it incorrectly?

Cheers

Comment: Remove the spaces between each byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put spaces between the bytes.

[See the documentation examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add#examples).

```
reg.exe Add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3"
/v Settings
/T REG_BINARY
/d 30000000feffffff03020000030000003e00000028000000000000005c030000a0050000840300006000000001000000
/f
```

Newlines added above for legibility, but that is one line.